# Echo a different string of text upon refresh/page load in php

Tags: php

I have a site that on the home page has a feature splash which consists of a couple of sentences of text.

Say if I had a file with about 5-6 different small blocks of text like the above that I wanted to echo out randomly each time someone hits my homepage, what is the best way to do this in php?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you tried already? The reading into array, choosing random number than showing the text seems fairly good solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation about [`file()`](http://php.net/file) and use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand):

```
$sentences = file('your-file.txt');

$keyNr = array_rand($sentences, 1);
var_dump($sentences[$keyNr]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Comfreak, I have tried out your solution but seem to be getting an error, though I am not sure if this is due to it being run within a WP page despite installing the Exec-php plugin? one other thing is if I am putting the sentences in a separate file, how should I assign them, is it just adding '' to the beginning and end of each?

Comment: @cheezynachos Which error are you geetting? You should separate your sentences by an EOL character ("End Of Line", just hit [Return] in your text editor).

Comment: sorry didn't include a number in the parameter var_dump(array_rand($sentences, 0)); so just changed 0 to 1, so now the output is random but is only displaying "int 0...int4...etc" not the sentence from the txt file?

Comment: @cheezynachos Sorry, my fault. Please try the updated answer. (`array_rand()` gives a random key - not its value.)

Comment: No worries @Comfreak, I think ther should be a ( before "array_rand"? but now getting another error, which I think is conflicting with the EXEC-php plugin "Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\wamp\www\weddingdresses.org.uk\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()’d code on line 11" unless you can see anything obvious, this might be a problem that we cannot crack? thanks for your time anyhow!

Comment: hold on though, I do have something....echoing out sentence, but it is not formatted and the is a string length  "(length=333)" showing up too...getting there!

Comment: @cheezynachos Yeah, there was a superfluous parenthesis. I used the function `var_dump()` for outputting the sentence in my sample. This is just for demonstration, you can use `echo $sentences[$keyNr];`, of course. [BTW, my name has two 'e's :)]

Comment: sorry @Comfreek. All working now... thanks for your help & Patience :)

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the text blocks in an array and choose one using the [rand()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.rand.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing your texts in a database and then selecting a random row from it with a query like the following:

```
select randomQuote from someTable order by rand() limit 1
```

This way you will never have to change your code, and you can simply update, insert new rows into the database or delete old ones etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [**array_rand()**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php&ei=JcspUsqaJpDPlAXXkYHICA&usg=AFQjCNF8F0jAGopK0kfX4npnAeJVPksGfQ&sig2=3qnt3gYwIaAwLuH2Qa-qPQ&bvm=bv.51773540,d.dGI) of PHP

```
<?php
$strings = array('Welcome Ryan', 'Welcome John', 'Welcome Mark', 'Welcome Mike', 'Welcome Jenna');
echo $strings[array_rand($strings)];
```